# Closure of the set of weak solutions of conservation laws

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the conservation law $$u_t + q(u)_x = 0 \quad \tag{CL}$$

A function $u$ is a weak solution of $(CL)$ if $u \in L^\infty_\text{loc}((0, \infty)\times \mathbb{R})$ and $$\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} uv_t + q(u)v_x \ \  dt \, dx = 0,$$ for every test function $v \in C_c^\infty((0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}).$

> Let $\{u_\epsilon\}$ be a sequence of weak solutions of $(\text{CL})$ and $u \in L^\infty((0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R})$.
>
> How does one prove that if, for every $\epsilon$, $\Vert u_\epsilon
>  \Vert_{L^\infty((0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R})} < B$ for some $B > 0$
>    and $u_\epsilon \to u$ in $L^1_\text{loc}((0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R})$,
>    then $u$ is a weak solution of $(\text{CL})$?

Also, is it possible to prove a stronger similar theorem?

Comment: If $u_\epsilon \to u$ in $L^1_{loc}([0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R})$, and the test function $\nu\in C^\infty_c([0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R})$, then this is an application of the dominated convergence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: What do you mean by a "stronger similar theorem"?

Comment: @Jeff 1: How so? 2: A theorem that gives the same conclusion under weaker assumptions.

Comment: 1) Since the integrand is bounded and has compact support, you can use a constant function for the dominating function in the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: 2) If you do not assume $u_\epsilon \to u$, then you can use the uniform boundedness to extract a subsequence converging weak-star in $L^\infty$. You run into trouble though, because weak convergence does not play nicely with nonlinear functions, like q. If you weaken the uniform boundedness assumption, you would need some further assumptions on $q$ so that $q(u_\epsilon) \to q(u)$ in $L^1_{loc}$.

Comment: @Jeff Issue 1) is still not quite clear to me; could you please add some details to the proof and write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K\subset (0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set containing the support of $\nu$. Then $u_\epsilon \to u$ in $L^1(K)$. By passing to a subsequence $u_k:=u_{\epsilon_k}$, we may assume $u_k \to u$ almost everywhere in $K$. Therefore $q(u_k) \to q(u)$ almost everywhere on $K$, and thus

$$u_k\nu_t + q(u_k)\nu_x \longrightarrow u \nu_t + q(u)\nu_x$$

almost everywhere on $K$ as $k\to \infty$. Since $\nu_x$ and $\nu_t$ are continuous functions on the compact set $K$, they are bounded. Provided $q$ is a locally bounded function, the sequence $q(u_k)$ is also uniformly bounded, hence

$$C:=\sup_k\| u_k\nu_t + q(u_k)\nu_x\|_{L^\infty(K)} < \infty.$$

So the sequence $u_k\nu_t + q(u_k)\nu_x$ is uniformly bounded by the $L^1(K)$ function $C$. So by the dominated convergence theorem

$$0 = \lim_{k\to \infty} \iint_K u_k\nu_t + q(u_k)\nu_x dt dx = \iint_K u \nu_t + q(u)\nu_x dtdx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^\infty u \nu_t + q(u)\nu_x dtdx .$$

Since this holds for arbitrary $\nu$ smooth with compact support, $u$ is a weak solution.

Comment: Thank you! Is it sufficient to assume only $u \in L_\text{loc}^\infty((0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Yes, because you only need uniform boundedness on the support of $\nu$.

Comment: More precisely, you need $\sup_{\epsilon} \|u_\epsilon\|_{L^\infty(K)} < \infty$ for all compact $K$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.